# Scope binding not updating in http call

Tags: angularjs, http, https, angular-http

I'm having trouble updating my scope from inside this function `updateRefresh()`.  The first iteration I can see that `message == "test"`, and then it does overwrite what's in the scope, but what it is binding to on my HTML page, `<span>{{refreshDomainStatus.message}}</span>`, is still bound to the object where `message="test"`

I have tried `$scope.$apply()` but it says that `$digest` is currently in progress.

```
app.controller('AssessmentController', ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout', 'ConnectionService', function ($scope, $http, $timeout, connectionService) {

    $scope.refreshDomainStatus = {
        message: "test"
    };

    var updateRefresh = function(updateKey) {
        $http.get('/assessment/api/update-refresh-domain/' + updateKey).success(function(response) {
            $scope.refreshDomainStatus = response.refreshDomainStatus;

            if (!response.refreshDomainStatus.halted) {
                $timeout(function () { updateRefresh(updateKey); }, 250);
            }
        });
    }
```

First Iteration:
[image: First Iteration]

Second Iteration:
[image: Second Iteration]

After finishing and inspecting the context:
[image: After]

Comment: If you `console.log(response.refreshDomainStatus);` inside your `updateRefresh()` method what is the output? Also, obvious question, but you are calling `updateRefresh()` somewhere to start the whole loop, right?

Comment: Yes, I am calling it to start the whole process off.  First iteration: `response.refreshDomainStatus => Object {error: false, message: "Retrieving list of users", halted: false}`.  `$scope.refreshDomainStatus => Object {error: true, message: "test", halted: false}`.  On the second iteration $scope.refreshDomainStatus has been set.  Seems like it's proper.  When I inspect the scope of the element that still says `"test": angular.element($0).scope().refreshDomainStatus => Object {message: "test", halted: false, error: false}`

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you set `$scope.refreshDomainStatus` to `response.refreshDomainStatus`?

```
    $http.get('/assessment/api/update-refresh-domain/' + updateKey).success(function(response) {
        $scope.refreshDomainStatus = response.refreshDomainStatus;

        if (!response.refreshDomainStatus.halted) {
            $timeout(function () { updateRefresh(updateKey); }, 250);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes.  You're right.  Sorry, I was trying to see if the issue was a reference issue.  Still doesn't work.

Comment: have you checked any console errors? your $http might not been resolved

Comment: First iteration: http://imgur.com/HLVzmHA  Second iteration: http://imgur.com/mzxDewv Upon finishing(inspecting the scope in the console): http://imgur.com/DCfQ4Bh

Comment: I updated the question extensively.  That should help.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I was creating two instances of the controller.  I guess I want some sort of singleton, but for future reference, this is bad:

```
        <div class="row" ng-controller="AssessmentController">
            <div class="col">
                <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="refresh()">Refresh</button>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div ng-show="" class="row" ng-controller="AssessmentController">
            <div class="col">
                <span>{{refreshStatus.message}}</span>    
            </div>
        </div>
```